# Why do Array.prototype.slice.call(nodeList) for DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, arrays, nodelist

Lots of JavaScript libraries (jQuery, Zepto) seem to be calling Array.prototype.slice.call on querySelectorAll(), getElementsByTag or ClassName results...

From reading many many similar questions/answers on StackOverflow I do understand that its to convert a NodeList result to a real Array so that you can invoke Array methods (slice, pop) on the results which are not available on NodeLists - but what I don't understand is why? You don't usually really need slice/pop on a list of DOM nodes + NodeLists already have a length property so they're traversable anyway.

Some answers seem to imply that its because a NodeList is pointing to live DOM objects. But again if you convert it to an Array, the references are still pointing to live DOM nodes - so whats the difference?

Or is it something else that I'm completely missing? Does it help Zepto/jQuery to somehow cache multiple property calls for DOM elements? (although I don't really see how since those are still live DOM references)

Comment: You're right that a `NodeList` is pointing to live DOM objects, but that means that when one is destroyed (or is no longer a valid item for the list), it and its spot is removed from the list. When you slice into an array, it's not the same "live" list - the elements themselves are live, but not the list itself. When an item is destroyed, its place is still kept in the array...but it won't represent the element - I'm guessing it becomes undefined or null.

Comment: @Ian if an array contains a reference to a DOM node then that node _cannot_ be garbage collected.

Comment: @Alnitak I see, well then I guess my comment would be changed to say something like ", its place is still kept in the array and the element stays, until there are no more references to it...then the value in the array would be undefined or null". Would that be correct?

Comment: @Ian no, that wouldn't be correct because the element _cannot_ have "no more references" because _there's still one in the array!_.  The only way to avoid that is to _explicitly_ set the array element to something else, so that the array no longer holds that reference,

Comment: Ah I see - yes, thanks thats certainly a plausible explanation... although - wouldn't that be a bad thing? I mean this would mean that a converted array would still maintain a reference to a DOM element that has potentially been removed - thus flagging it as "still in use" and signalling to the garbage collector that it shouldn't be removed from memory?

Comment: @user1768759 it would get removed when the array itself is garbage collected.

Comment: ah you guys are faster than me with replying so I'm just repeating myself here :) ... also BTW it seems that querySelectorAll() is different as it returns a static nodelist so an array.prototype.slice.call makes even less sense there

Comment: @user1768759 interesting - I didn't know that QSA's result was non-live, but in any event it makes it simpler just to take a copy because then any dependent code doesn't have to care about whether the nodelist is live or not.

Comment: @Alnitak thanks - but wouldn't it then be cleaner just to work with a nodelist rather than converting it to an array? this part confuses me because every library that I've looked at today does the array slice - and I thought I might have been missing something important there... just not sure what? :-)

Comment: @Alnitak haha what the heck am I thinking?

Comment: @user1768759 I wouldn't be surprised if they use the array slice to just be consistent everywhere. I'm pretty sure libraries attempt to take advantage of built in methods, like `getElementById`, `querySelectorAll`, etc., so the library doesn't know exactly what kind of list will be returned. It's their way of making sure you get the static list of elements that are returned from whatever underlying method at that exact point in time, and will always be available (unless you manipulate the list later).

Comment: @Ian I think that's what I just said ;-)

Comment: @Alnitak I just need to stop talking...

Comment: Thanks for the discussion guys - consistency certainly makes sense. I am researching this for my own minimal library oriented towards mobile devices - so was actually looking to remove stuff that libraries put in there to be backwards compatible. And possibly redundant stuff - I'm still not sure if an array slice is worth keeping for general stuff - it is an extra call/operation after all and in essence it does create a potentially large array of elements - which does take extra memory... dunno, will need to do some more reading :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You don't usually really need slice/pop on a list of DOM nodes

Actually, you do, and that's exactly why it's necessary.

For example, how else would `.eq()`, `.first()`, etc. work.  The jQuery object contains a *copy* of the `NodeList` in an array, and then the individual methods take slices of that array.  Similarly, you can't `.add()` nodes to a `NodeList`.

Furthermore, those arrays need to remain valid even if the elements therein are subsequently removed from the DOM.  The references in the array are still valid, and can be used to reinsert those elements back into the DOM.

If all you had was a live `NodeList` the elements would automagically disappear from the list when they're removed from the DOM, and would be lost forever unless you had a separate reference to them.

Comment: @TinyGiant _some_ `NodeList` objects are live, some are static.  The one returned by `querySelectorAll` is static.  Suggest you read the substantial comment thread on the question above.

Comment: Note that Array.prototype.slice.call(nodeList) is not working on some IE versions if the nodeList is an SVG element

Answer (score 0):

> ...because a NodeList is pointing to live DOM objects...

No, this is a misunderstanding. The key is not that each of the nodes in the list is a "live" DOM object (true but irrelevant), it's that the **list itself** is "live" . In other words the contents of the list may change (or even grow or shrink) at any time whenever the DOM is changed.

If you perform operations on the items in the list that change the DOM, the list itself may change on the fly while you're using it. That means under the covers your code can get into really weird recursion and/or performance problems, without you realizing it and without hardly any indication in the source code.

Converting the NodeList to a regular Javascript Array removes this "liveness" of the list itself, and thus removes the opportunity to shoot yourself in the foot.

Comment: @TinyGiant Some certainly are, e.g. `aNode.childNodes`.  Your example uses `querySelectorAll` which returns a non-live NodeList.