# what's the role of slice method here ? why need it?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

In ES5 if have a NodeList and want to loop through it must first convert it to Array with `slice` and `call`. I can't understand correctly how this statement works. I need explanation.

```
let nodeList = document.querySelectorAll('div');
let nToArr   = Array.prototype.slice.call(nodeList);
// Then Loop Through it ....
```

Comment: This is might help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13295361/why-do-array-prototype-slice-callnodelist-for-dom-elements

Comment: I'd start with the documentation: [`slice`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice), [`call`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/call)

Comment: Why not `Array.from(nodeList)` ?

Comment: you can also just do [...nodeList] to transform it into an array.

Comment: Or [`NodeList.forEach`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList/forEach) for that matter...

Comment: I think Array.from was introduced in Es6, so maybe this is to include browsers that don't support that?

Comment: i already know Array.form , i need to know how that line work each segment of it

Comment: why use slice ?

Comment: @canon okay !  how does this specific thing work ?

Comment: the slice function is used to normally extract a subarray from an array. But by setting the this value ( call(nodeList)) as the nodelist, we're tricking the function into making a shallow copy of the nodelist as an array.

Comment: @canon You misunderstood :D , you understood my intention, could you explain it to me?

Comment: @Ameya Rane Thanks , that's what i need , actually i wrote the question without specification